# phpstorm regex search and replace

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I trying to regex replace `echo $review->helpful;` with `echo stripslashes($review->helpful);`  in PHPstorm without any luck.

I tried `echo  \$.*\;` with `echo stripslashes($1);` but didn't worked I get malformed replacement string.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `phpstorm`, but the reason you're getting a `malformed replacement string` error is probably because you're using `$1` to reference the first grouping, when there is no first grouping.

Try using this:

```
echo \$(.*?);
```

And replace again with this, like you originally did:

```
echo stripslashes($1);
```

Basically all I did was group `.*` so that `$1` would be able to reference it, and added a lazy modifier to the star just to avoid any weird stuff happening later on in the parse. I also removed the `\`, since `;` itself doesn't stand for anything in regex, escaping it is unnecessary.

Here's a test to verify that it works: http://fiddle.re/9e47